# code generate with xtend in xtext project

Tags: code-generation, xtext, generated-code, xtend

I'm working on xtext project and I'm generating objects through .xtext file.
I want to add new attribute to one of the generated object.
I saw in http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/customizing-xtext-metamodel-inference-using-xtend2/
the following code is generating a temp variable in ObjectValue 
but i want temp to be of type MyObject.

How to do so? where can i read about it?

```
import org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.GenModelPackage
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.BasicEMap$Entry
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EClass
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EPackage
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcoreFactory
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcorePackage
import org.eclipse.xtext.GeneratedMetamodel
import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ecoreInference.IXtext2EcorePostProcessor

class CodeGeneratorClass implements IXtext2EcorePostProcessor {

    override process(GeneratedMetamodel metamodel) {
        metamodel.EPackage.process
    }

    def process(EPackage p) {
        for (c : p.EClassifiers.filter(typeof(EClass))) {
            if (c.name == "ObjectValue") {
                c.handle
            }
        }
    }

    def handle (EClass c) {
    val attr = EcoreFactory::eINSTANCE.createEAttribute
    attr.name = "temp"
    attr.EType = EcorePackage::eINSTANCE.EString
    c.EStructuralFeatures += attr
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `MyObject` must be described either by an `EClass` or an `EDataType`. A plain Java Object won't do it.

If `MyObject` is an `EDataType` then you must add an `EAttribute` in the `handle` method. Your `handle` method is almost right, only the `EType` must be adjusted:

```
attr.EType = MyPackage::eINSTANCE.MyObject
```

Otherwise: If `MyObject` is an `EClass` then you must add an `EReference` instead of an `EAttribute`. The `handle` method for this case looks like this:

```
def handleReference(EClass c){
    val ref = EcoreFactory::eINSTANCE.createEReference
    ref.name = "temp"
    ref.EType = MyPackage::eINSTANCE.MyObject
    c.EStructuralFeatures += ref
}
```

**EDIT**

In order to define a new, minimal EDataType and hook it up into the model the following snippet should work:

```
def void process(GeneratedMetamodel it){
     // create new dynamic EDataType
     val dataType = EcoreFactory::eINSTANCE.createEDataType => [
        name = 'MyObject'
        instanceTypeName = 'java.package.with.MyObject' 
    ]

    // register new EDataType in own model package
    EPackage.EClassifiers += dataType

    // attach as EAttribute to appropriate EClasses
    EPackage.EClassifiers.filter(typeof(EClass)).filter[name == 'ObjectValue'].forEach[
        EStructuralFeatures += EcoreFactory::eINSTANCE.createEAttribute => [
            name = "temp"
            EType = dataType
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: @DanaKlein: Hmm. There are several ways to define an `EDataType`. And whether or not an `EDataType` is really the right thing is another question. For easy and simple things you can use the predefined stuff from `EcorePackage` - every `getXyz` method returning `EDataType`. If you really want to define your own EDataType then you should first consult a book about EMF.

Comment: Thanks! 
Is it possible to return an Iterator object?

s.t. the generated code would look like:
public Iterator<T> getIterator(){}

Comment: Technically: I'm quite sure but I can't tell you offhand. But "Iterator" sound like you are trying to compute something. Then neither an attribute nor a reference would be the right thing to put into the model. In that case an operation sounds more appropriate.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over a object elements. 
so for that i want to generate a method with the signature:  public Iterator<T> getIterator(){...}